# Getting the error "index 1024 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1024" when trying to traverse the image columnwise

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, anaconda

I am trying to traverse the pixels of an image columnwise. The dimensions of the image are 1280x1024. 
When I write the following code, I get the error

```
for i in range(0,cols):
        for j in range(0,rows):
            image[i][j]=0
```

but when I do this, I don't get the error

```
for i in range(0,rows):
    for j in range(0,cols):
        image[i][j]=0
```

please help!!

Comment: What is the question? You’ve solved your error yourself. Use the second bit of code to loop over the image!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `opencv` `image[i]` is `i`s row of the `image`. So in first case instead of

```
...
image[i][j]
```

you'd, probably, want

```
...
image[j][i]
```

Otherwise you, obviously, get an error as you index rows (of range 0-1023) with columns indices (of range 0-1279).